# Rolling back Transaction with Spring - AOP

Tags: hibernate, spring, aop

I am quite new to AOP-Spring. I am stuck with transaction issue(Testing the rollback with AOP). I guess I might be doing something basically wrong. or there is conflict with existing configs.

My Spring config file

```
<beans...>
     <!-- This TX is I am interested in -->      
     <bean id="transactionManager"
           class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
               <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource"/>  
     </bean>

      <bean id="registriesTransactionManager"
           class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
         <property name="dataSource" ref="registriesDataSource"/>
     </bean> <!-- There are 2 datasorce for AS400 and a transaction for one of them-->

     <aop:config>
         <aop:advisor pointcut="execution(* se.unox.pejl.service.PejlAnalysisService.* (..))" advice-ref="txMySqlAdvice"/>                    
         <! --- + many more --> 
     </aop:config>

     <tx:advice id="txMySqlAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
       <tx:attributes>
         <tx:method name="get*" read-only="true" />
         <tx:method name="*" />             
         <tx:method name="cleanPejlValues" propagation="REQUIRED" rollback-for="Throwable"/>    
       </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice> 

</beans>
```

My Service implementation

```
public class PejlAnalysisServiceImpl implements PejlAnalysisService, InitializingBean     {
    @Override
    public void cleanPejlValues() {
         List<String> idsToDelete= pejlDataDao.getPejlIds(Calendar.getInstance().getTime(), pejlType);

         logger.debug("TRYING TO DELETE these IDS: " + idsToDelete);

         numDeletedValues += cisternDao.deleteCistern(idsToDelete);

         logger.debug("DELETED " + numDeletedValues);
         numDeletedValues += pejlDataDao.deletePejlValues(idsToDelete);
     }
 }
```

My DAO that i am throwing exception from

```
public class PejlDataDaoMySqlImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<PejlDataInValue,String> implements PejlDataDao {

  @Override
  public int deletePejlValues(List<String> pejlIds)      {          
    throw new RuntimeException("THROW INTENTIONALLY");          
  }
}
```

I want the deleted rows by CisternDao (Table tbl_cistern) to be rolled back after I am (intentionally) throwing exception from another Dao that's suppose to delete data from Parent table.

However, my rollback is not working. The table tbl_cistern data is still gone.

What am I doing wrong? (I am using Spring 3.1 , Spring AOP -3.1 , Hibernate 3.6 , Tomcat6 )

===============================================================================

EDIT.

Here is my AOP StackTrace. It does saying Rolling back, but my rows from first table is still gone. Its an existing application. Wonder if DomainServiceImpl TX is interfering.

```
2011-10-12 11:46:27,726 DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.PejlAnalysisServiceImpl.cleanPejlValues]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-Throwable
2011-10-12 11:46:27,726 DEBUG - Creating new transaction with name [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.PejlAnalysisServiceImpl.cleanPejlValues]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT,-Throwable
2011-10-12 11:46:27,726 DEBUG - Acquired Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] for JDBC transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,726 DEBUG - Acquired Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] for JDBC transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,727 DEBUG - Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] to manual commit
2011-10-12 11:46:27,727 DEBUG - Switching JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] to manual commit
2011-10-12 11:46:27,727 DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,727 DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,727 DEBUG - Initializing transaction synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:27,727 DEBUG - Initializing transaction synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:27,728 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.PejlAnalysisServiceImpl.cleanPejlValues]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,728 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.PejlAnalysisServiceImpl.cleanPejlValues]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,729 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,729 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,729 DEBUG - Participating in existing transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,729 DEBUG - Participating in existing transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,729 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,729 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,730 DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,730 DEBUG - Bound value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,730 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,730 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Participating in existing transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Participating in existing transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,734 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Participating in existing transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Participating in existing transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Getting transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,735 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,737 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,737 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.DomainServiceImpl.getDomainData]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,737 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,737 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,789 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:27,789 DEBUG - Retrieved value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] bound to thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.PejlAnalysisServiceImpl.cleanPejlValues] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: THROWN INTENTIONALLY
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Completing transaction for [se.unox.pejl.service.impl.PejlAnalysisServiceImpl.cleanPejlValues] after exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: THROWN INTENTIONALLY
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: THROWN INTENTIONALLY
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Applying rules to determine whether transaction should rollback on java.lang.RuntimeException: THROWN INTENTIONALLY
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [Throwable]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Winning rollback rule is: RollbackRuleAttribute with pattern [Throwable]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:28,396 DEBUG - Triggering beforeCompletion synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:28,397 DEBUG - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] from thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,397 DEBUG - Removed value [org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionHolder@160088f] for key [org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl@1a0280d] from thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,397 DEBUG - Initiating transaction rollback
2011-10-12 11:46:28,397 DEBUG - Initiating transaction rollback
2011-10-12 11:46:28,397 DEBUG - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,397 DEBUG - Rolling back JDBC transaction on Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,398 DEBUG - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:28,398 DEBUG - Triggering afterCompletion synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:28,398 DEBUG - Clearing transaction synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:28,398 DEBUG - Clearing transaction synchronization
2011-10-12 11:46:28,398 DEBUG - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] from thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,398 DEBUG - Removed value [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.ConnectionHolder@6113e0] for key [org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource@ee003d] from thread [http-8080-1]
2011-10-12 11:46:28,399 DEBUG - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] after transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:28,399 DEBUG - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] after transaction
2011-10-12 11:46:28,399 DEBUG - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2011-10-12 11:46:28,399 DEBUG - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
2011-10-12 11:30:36,577 DEBUG - Releasing JDBC Connection [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pejldatastorenorway?autoReconnect=true, UserName=dbpejl@localhost, MySQL-AB JDBC Driver] after transaction
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.  Or should I say problem solved, not really understood why .

Changed my Transaction bean class from  org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager

to

org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager

And Its working.

```
 <bean id="transactionManager"  class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
      <!--  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"> -->
     <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mySqlSessionFactory"></property>

   <!--  <property name="dataSource" ref="mySqlDataSource"/>  -->       
</bean>
```

Too numb right now, going home. Anybody could shed light on why is this so?

Comment: If you are doing the delete via hibernate I think the problem is not solved.  Hibernate is not sending the delete statements to the database - so changing to HibernateTransactionManager (which is the right thing to do) might be masking the original problem. You can check this by calling session.flush() before throwing the exception.  I still think the issue is because of mysql storage engine.

Comment: Can you please link why using HibernateTransactionManager is better? Thanks.

Comment: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html has some info.  Basically you want a single Hibernate Session to be created for the whole transaction instead of one per dao call. HibernateTransactionManager will ensure that.

Comment: SELECT TABLE_NAME, ENGINE
 FROM information_schema.TABLES
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pejldatastorenorway'

Returned "InnoDB".

Comment: One more thing - how is the hibernate sessionfactory getting the datasource, is it injected via spring or directly configured in a hibernate.cfg.xml.  That is one reason why it wouldn't work with DataSourceTransactionManager but work once changed to HibernateTransactionManager.

Comment: oh. How did i not get the notification of your question?

Comment: Not sure If i understood. But the injection is through Spring. My hibernate.cfg.xml has just entity mappings. 

    <hibernate-configuration>
       <session-factory>
        <mapping class="..."/>
       </session-factory>

applicationContext.xml has <bean id="mySqlDataSource" /> 

 <bean id="mySqlSessionFactory" ...>
       <property name="configLocation" value="WEB-INF/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>

And 
 <bean id="pejlAnalysisDao" class="PejlAnalysisDaoImpl">

Comment: Not clear from the above. You should not have the hibernate.connection.* properties in hibernate.cfg.xml. The SessionFactory bean in the spring should have property datasource pointed to the dataSource bean - that is what I meant by injected via spring.

Comment: No. I dont have it there. i only have my entities defined in hibernate.cfg.file.  applicationContext.xml
<bean id="mySqlSessionFactory" class="AnnotationSessionFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="mySqlDataSource">
           <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}  </prop>

The variables you see are defined in another properties file (that reads values for different deployment environments).

You mentioned //That is one reason why it wouldn't work//. Which case of injection would it not work? Thanks

Comment: It would not work if the dataSource was not injected into sessionFactory, but the connection is directly obtained by Hibernate using the configuration in hibernate.cfg.xml

Answer (score 2):

Try changing your AOP expressions to also include the service interfaces (if they are not covered). I have had issues where my service interfaces are in a different package from the service implementations, and if they are not covered by the AOP expression the transactions are not started/committed/rolled.

Also, if this is a webapp, consider dropping AOP in favor of Spring's [OpenSessionInViewFilter](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/OpenSessionInViewInterceptor.html) which opens a session when a request comes in, and commits/rolls it back after it returns/throws.

Lastly, I use the IntelliJ IDE which has great Spring support - you can click an AOP declaration in an XML file and see a popup list of all methods the pattern matches - really helps with debugging AOP.

Comment: I thinkt you're on the rigt track here. Try debugging your code and see if the Advice is actually called when it's supposed to first, and only afterwards deal with the actual business logic inside it. Also, I've always found it a lot clearer and cleaner to define my  Aspect pointcuts as a certain annotation, and then place that annotation on top of the desired methods.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer SingleShot. I am debugging but still confused. See the edit above.

Comment: I voted is useful, thanks for new insights. :) But about changes (dropping AOP or using intelliJ) I can only modify so much as the application is already in use since years. Depends on how long I will be workign on this project too. And yes. I will change it to annotation (@Transactional) instead of existing XML config.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to add `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>` to your context.  This is an instruction to apply the aspects to your beans.  `aop:config` and `tx:advice` just setup an aspect which I think is not getting applied.

You can also verify if your classes are being aspected and transactions are started / rolled back by turning on info logging for spring.

As a side note if you are using java 1.5 or later it is much better / easier to use annotations (@Transactional) instead of the XML based configuration.

Comment: sorry <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/> did not help. :-(

Comment: I got rid of XML based configuration and using @Trasactional now. 

problem still persists. Logs says its rolling back (something) but the data in MySql database is gone.

Comment: What is the storage engine - if it is MyISAM I think it doesn't support transactions. You need to change to InnoDB.

Comment: Its InnoDB. I had  hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect in my config.

Already tried changing it to 

hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLInnoDBDialect

Also tried <bean id="mySqlDataSource" p:aurocommit="false"

did not work. Problem is solved with changinh Transaction to HibernateTransactionManager.

Comment: not the dialect - the storage engine associated with the table in the database. You can find info on how to check and change - http://www.electrictoolbox.com/mysql-table-storage-engine/

Comment: Just left the office. I will check accordingly tomorrow. But just to state.. When I said it's innodb , I checked that through mysql workbench - table. But I will check again tomorrow at work.